# Why can't ImageMagick read any fonts on my machine?

Tags: fonts, troubleshooting, imagemagick

I'm trying to run `montage`.

```
montage `ls ?.png` `ls ??.png` -tile 6x3 -geometry 32x32 tile.jpg
```

But I am getting this error regarding fonts.

```
montage: unable to read font `(null)' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1239.
```

Why can't it read any fonts?

Someone suggested I run `montage -list font` but it doesn't return anything. I'm running OS X 10.11, and ImageMagick 6.9.3-0.

Comment: I don't know the product, but the way the error is return, it's suggesting its found some kind element/item that it thinks is a 'null'. Check this out as the error is almost the exact same aside from the number at the end of the path: https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=20529

Comment: @AaronLayfield One of those solutions actually does work... I'll post it below.

Comment: Good stuff, won't be able to mark your answer for a couple days, but definitely submit it for future viewers.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my direct question, ImageMagick requires a `type.xml` document containing a list of all the fonts on the machine. While it seems like this list should be auto-generated, it is not.

As @AaronLayfield mentioned above, there is a manual way to generate the font list as explained [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=20529). Below is my version of the workaround:

1. Save this perl script as `imagick_type_gen.pl` http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/imagick_type_gen
2. Open Terminal and `cd` into the directory you saved the file to, then change the permissions on the file with `chmod 755 imagick_type_gen.pl`.
3. Create the `.magick` folder in your home directory with `mkdir ~/.magick`.
4. Run the script and export the output with `./imagick_type_gen.pl > ~/.magick/type.xml`.

Now it should work.